# Google Drive integration in android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Hello Friends,
              Actually these days i am working on google drive integration with my android application. But i am facing one problem. When i take a image from my file manager to upload to google drive then while uploading my image it doesn't ask for any type of google login and by default add to my device's default account of drive. But i want that my application will redirect to web service to login with google account and then come back to my account to uplaod my file..

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize your google account first.
REFER: 
https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart 
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```